# Django Site not showing Logo on Facebook, Linkedin

Tags: django

Can someone please help me in order to fix this simple issue? The site is working properly, but the logo not. What i am doing: i type the name of the site e.g `www.foo.com` and the head is taken ok with the title of the site etc, but the logo not. The same issue happen on Linkedin also, so what should i do?

This is my head_css.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link href=" {% static 'css/fontawesome-free-5.0.2/web-fonts-with-css/css/fontawesome-all.min.css'   %}" rel="stylesheet">

<link href=" {% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'   %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/custom.css'   %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href=" {% static 'css/navbar-top.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static 'favicon/favicon.ico' %}">


<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{%  static 'favicon/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{%  static 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{%  static 'favicon/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
<link rel="manifest" href="{%  static 'favicon/webmanifest' %}">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Comment: Try `{% load static %}`

Comment: there is that tag! thank you!

Comment: Mind accepting my answer? :D

Comment: shouldn't it be `rel="shortcut icon"` instead of `rel="stylesheet"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `{% load static %}` instead of `staticfiles`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with this:

```
<!-- 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="201">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="384">
<meta property="og:title" content="title of site">
<meta property="og:description" content="description">
<meta property="og:url" content="url">
<meta property="og:image" content="{%  static 'favicon/logo.jpg' %}"> -->
```